# Azure Pipelines DownloadBuildArtifacts - how to define download parallelism?

Tags: azure-pipelines

We use a `DownloadBuildArtifacts` task in our Azure Pipeline.

The download is done by the Azure Agent service, in particular by `Agent.PluginHost.exe`, which opens a very large amount of parallel network connections to download one single file, which causes some issues for us.

So we would like to restrict the number of parallel network connections.

There's the following information in the Azure Pipeline log:

```
...
Download artifact to: xxxx
Using default max parallelism.
Max dedup parallelism: 192
...
```

The number 192 matches more or less the number of parallel network connections we see for one single file download.

We've checked and also tried the parameter `parallelizationLimit` for `DownloadBuildArtifacts`, but this is something different: it limits the number of *files* to download simultaneously (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

Is there a way to reduce the download parallelism i.e. number of network connections for a single file download used by `DownloadBuildArtifacts`?